# How does Views Node Field module manifest itself in Views UI?

Tags: views, nodes

I've installed the Views Node Field 7.x-1.0 module, but can't figure out how to access its features in the Views UI.

Given an existing view, what are the steps to get to where I can add a Teaser as if it were a field?

I've verified that the Views Node UI module is active in the Updates report.

In a view, on a page, under Field I click on Add. If I try to search on teaser, nothing comes up.  If I filter on Field, I don't see any fields that seem relevant.

Comment: I added the dev version and it works fine. The field is 'Content: Node field' and under build mode it gave me all of the available view modes.